# Migrate Native Module from Gradle Experimental Plugin to Stable Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cmake, gradle-experimental

I have an Android Library project which has a part in C/C++ via [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html).
The project started half of a year ago so we chose to use [Experimental Plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) because of better NDK support.
I'm using `gradle-experimental:0.8.2`right now. I have a `com.android.model.native` module and i would like to migrate it to `gradle:2.2.0`. The only option i see in [Gradle Android Plugin DSL](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/) is:

- AppExtension: android extension for `com.android.application` projects.
- LibraryExtension: android extension for `com.android.library` projects.
- TestExtension: android extension for `com.android.test` projects.

So the question is how to make a pure native module in gradle with stable gradle plugin?

Here is my current native module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.native'

apply from: "../config.gradle"
def config = ext.configuration

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = config.compileSdkVersion
        buildToolsVersion = config.buildToolsVersion

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = config.minimumSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = config.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = '1.0'
        }
        ndk {
            moduleName = 'apicore'
            platformVersion = config.minimumSdkVersion
            cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
            cppFlags.add("-pthread")
            cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
            cppFlags.add("-frtti")
            stl = "gnustl_static"
            abiFilters.addAll(config.targetPlatforms)
            ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log'])
        }
        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    source {
                        //include "someFile.txt"
                        // This is ignored.
                        exclude "main.cpp"
                        exclude "misc/APITest.cpp"
                        exclude "misc/APITest.h"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you really want. Put in your `build.gradle` of application `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'` and inform us what is happening when your app finish the build of the project.

Comment: Stable gradle doesn't have `com.android.model.native` plugin

Comment: This is your `build.gradle` for the app, there is another `build.gradle` to the project. It is there where you find the version of your gradle.

Comment: @RodrigoPaixão I can change my gradle version thats not the problem. The stable gradle doesnt have native module. You really don't understand what i want. i am using this: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

Comment: I have the same issue, sadly the migration guide does not mention anything. In the googlesamples for gradle 2.2 and ndk they avoid having native library modules and instead just have a script which builds all of the libraries and it seems like it is the only option currently. For reference gradle-experimental sample with com.android.model.native https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/gradle-experimental/hello-libs, ndk-build sample without https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master-ndkbuild/hello-libs

Comment: I really don't know what should i think about this. I have a feeling that I overlooked something. They put the native module to experimental plugin for reason. I have separate module for JNI and pure C++ stuff i think it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just migrated my project from [Gradle Experimental Plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) to [Gradle plugin for Android](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system). The current Gradle plugin for Android still not provide something what com.android.model.native extension provided from the experimental plugin which is an ability to create a pure native module. I have to realise that i don't even need that. What i did to replace the com.android.model.native module is i made a library module where i handle the native code and building of my native libraries and i just copy the native libraries where i need them. Of course the module generate the .aar but thats not a problem i just don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create *CMakeLists.txt* or *Android.mk* to build your "**libapicore.so**", if you want to move to stable gradle plugin.
I think you should do next steps:

1. For easy migration move your *.h, .c, .cpp* to the
   `root_folder_of_project\app\src\main\cpp`
2. Also add there **CMakeLists.txt**. It should look like:

   `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)`
   `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread")`

   `add_library(apicore SHARED
                #here add your cpp sources
                mysource1.cpp
                mysource2.cpp
                #do not include main.cpp misc/APITest.cpp misc/APITest.h
                )`

   `#include libraries needed for apicore lib
   target_link_libraries(apicore
                         android
                         log
                         )`
3. Now rewrite your app's build.gradle and point it to CMakeLists.txt:
   `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`
   `android {` 
   `compileSdkVersion = 25
    buildToolsVersion = '25.0.2'`
   `defaultConfig {
        applicationId = 'com.your.app'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        ndk {
            abifilters 'armeabi-v7a' /*,'armeabi', etc.*/
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-19',
                          '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', /*or gcc*/
                          '-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti',
                          '-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=exceptions',
                          '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static' /*CMake uses by default*/
            }
        }
    }`
   `buildTypes {...}`
   `externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
     }`
   `}` 
   `dependencies {...}`
   With this you will build your android application with your native **"libapicore.so"** inside.

Comment: Thank you for answer, you wrapped it up nicely. The problem is, this way i am basically merging my app module which is pure java and android stuff with pure c/c++ stuff. From my point of view the app should be divided at least into 3 parts: 1. Main Android App module 2. JNI/NDK stuff(wrapper for c/c++) 3. C/C++ stuff

Comment: Okay, understood. It is possible. Did you see the **hello-libs** sample from [google github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs) ? This can answer your questions. But It is built into 2 parts: 1) Main Android App module; 2) JNI/NDK stuff + C/C++ stuff