# Android NDK: How to build for ARM64-v8a with minimumSdkVersion = 19

Tags: android, c++, gradle, android-ndk, abi

I have an Android Library project which has a part in C/C++ via Android NDK. I want to build my native code for all architectures. If i set `minSdkVersion`to 21 it all works fine. but i need to have lower `minSdkVersion`(SDK 19) if i set `minSdkVersion` to 19 the ARM64-v8a version is not built. I know that there are no ARM64-v8a devices running SDK 19. How can i achieve to have all platforms built in one APK and have `minSdkVersion` 19?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there is typo in "*minimumSdkVersion*". The right attribute is "***minSdkVersion***".
However, arm64-v8a library should be *successfully* built for API 19, because NDK build scripts will automatically take right set of platform headers and libraries.
If you are using **Gradle** build scripts try to set it as one of target ABIs:

`ndk {
        abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a' 
}`

Then, explicitly set target platform for native build.
 If you use **CMake**, then in gradle script set:

`externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
            arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-19'
          }
}`

If you use **ndk-build**, then in your Application.mk set:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

I hope that helps. Please, write details if it will not build.

Comment: You are right, its minSdkVersion, but the build doesn't produce arm64-v8a libraries if i set minSdkVersion to 19. And only changing it back to 21 makes gradle build these arm64 .so files

Comment: I found that previously there was bug in Android Studio 2.0.x. See here
[issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195135).
What are you using? Provide details.

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.2.3 and experimental gradle plugin 0.8.2. So basically what i have to do is set the minSdkVersion to 21 and individually set 19 for every every platform except arm64-v8a

Comment: Oh, experimental plugin has enough problems. Yes, basically, you will need to separate your build. Here is interesting [link](http://www.eegeo.com/2016/10/native-android-development-using-android-studio/) how guys are struggling with experimental plugin.

Comment: Well i am struggling with experimental plugin too. I would like to migrate the project to stable version. I also asked few questions about that, with not so much success. [question1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909370/migrate-native-module-from-gradle-experimental-plugin-to-stable-gradle) [question2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906107/how-to-access-versioncode-from-task-in-gradle-experimental-plugin)